# Wrap content using directive and transclude

Tags: angularjs

I would like to surround and input with a wrapper which contains multiple divs. I would want the input to be placed inside of the div called "my-content". I'm using a directive to achieve this, but it's not being placed inside the wrapper.

These are the templates I tried:
This doesn't work

```
<div class="wrapper" >
  <div class="left-side" > </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="top-side"> </div>
    <div class="my-content" ng-transclude ></div>
    <div class="bottom-side"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side"> </div>
</div>
```

But this works

```
<div class="wrapper" >
  <div class="left-side" > </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="top-side"> </div>
    <input class="my-content" ng-transclude />
    <div class="bottom-side"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side"> </div>
</div>
```

Directive is defined as such:

```
app.directive('wrapMe', function(){

  return {
      restrict: "A", 
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true
  };

});
```

So to reiterate, I would like whatever has the wrap-me directive to be placed inside the div with 'my-content' class and ng-transclude. Am I missing something here?

Plunker link:  http://plnkr.co/edit/oQtWNCBBuc61bRwzDjHP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  Just change `transclude` option to `element` and you're done. Basically you want both the `input` element and its contents to be transcluded. The previous option (`transclude: true`) only transcludes the contents, which is empty, that's why it didn't work.

```
app.directive('wrapMe', function(){

  return {
      restrict: "A", 
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      transclude: 'element',
      replace: true
  };

});
```

Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IX0ELKR4wKOPtt2vO6FB?p=preview